# Swift: Disable or Clear Undo for a TextField

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, undo

When selecting NumberPad for a TextField, the iPad displays a full keyboard, so I have created a function to simply remove all characters that are not numeric.  However, if a Non-numeric key is pressed and then the user presses Undo on the keyboard, the App Crashes.

How do I disable the Undo function for the TextField or at least clear the Undo Stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simple in the end, I used undoManager removeAllActions, but instead of just needing:

```
undoManager?.removeAllActions()
```

as a line, I needed:

```
myTextField.undoManager?.removeAllActions()
```

I placed this in the DidChange Action for the TextField.

Answer (score 0):

Add `UITextFieldDelegate` in your controller.
In your `viewDidLoad()` assign `yourTextField.delegate = self`. Than implement this method

```
public func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    return false // This will disable clear button
}
```

Also for replacing text I would suggest use

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{//Your Logic Here
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to disable or Clear the UNDO Stack not the TextField itself